# XElement value is always null

Tags: xml, xml-serialization, linq-to-xml

I have a XML document

```
<Root>
<Member xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="urn:abc:xyz">
    <ID>123</Id>    
    <Name>
      <First>ABC</First>
      <Last>XYZ</Last>
    </Name>
    <DateOfBirth>1900-01-01</DateOfBirth>
    <Gender>Male</Gender>
  </Member>
  </Root>
```

Here is my code

```
XElement xmlRootElement = xdoc.Element("Root");
var x = xmlRootElement.Element("Member");
```

Why is the Member always Null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Member` element belongs to the `urn:abc:xyz` namespace.
Try the following:

```
XNamespace ns = "urn:abc:xyz";
var x = xmlRootElement.Element(ns + "Member");
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get Member element is:

```
var elem = XElement.Parse("<Root><Member xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns=\"urn:abc:xyz\"><ID>123</ID><Name><First>ABC</First><Last>XYZ</Last></Name><DateOfBirth>1900-01-01</DateOfBirth><Gender>Male</Gender></Member></Root>");
var ns = elem.XPathSelectElement("/*").GetDefaultNamespace();
var x = elem.Element(ns + "Member");
Console.WriteLine(x.CreateNavigator().OuterXml);
```